# Matching regex groups starting from the end

Tags: regex

I can have the following strings:

```
20200124 (year-month-day)
202001   (year-month)
0124     (month-day)
24       (day)
```

I am trying to come up with a regex to be able to match all the above strings based on capturing groups.
My regex:

```
^(?<year>\d{4})?(?<month>\d{2})?(?<day>\d{2})$
```

Note: so far I did not consider any type of validation for the inputed string, I'm currently interested in matching them correctly.

There are some issues with the regex since it doesn't match correctly in all the cases.

Eg: `20200124` is matched correctly while `202001` also matches but `01` is matched in the `day` group instead of the `month` group. Or `2020` matches the `month` and the `day` group

I'm not sure if its possible to match all the posibilities listed above with just one regex?

Comment: You have listed `"24"` under "month-day"; are you saying that `"24"` is Feb 4th? If so, you have also listed `"24"` under "day", so how do you distinguish which way to parse it?

Comment: I have updated the question with more clear examples

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the year-month case makes all possibilities irregular and I would parse the string manually. You didn't specify programming language so this is pseudo code:

```
if date.length = 6 then
    month = date.right(2)
    year = date.left(4)
else
    day = date.right(2)
    month = date.substring(date.length-4, date.length-2)
    year = date.substring(date.length-8, date.length-6)
end
```

+/- 1 where needed. Depending on the substring implementation you may need to add additional checks for string length.